# Add cid image in thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following code :

```
Context context = getContext(transaction.getQuoteId(),transaction);
body = templateEngine.process("....html", context);

MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
FileSystemResource logo = new FileSystemResource(new File("/images/logo.png"));
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);
helper.addInline("logo", logo);
helper.setFrom(fromEmail);
helper.setTo("...);
helper.setSubject("....");
helper.setText(body, true);
javaMailSender.send(mail);
```

In html code I have:

```
<td align="center" style="line-height: 0px; text-align:start;">
    <img style="display:block; line-height:0px;margin-left: 30px;" src="cid:${logo}" width="200" alt="logo">
</td>
```

I also tried using `th:src="'cid:logo'"` but it didn't work. When I receive an email the image in not rendered.

The image resides inside :

```
src/main/resources/images/logo.png
```

I also allowed access to "/images/.., /resources/.." in HttpSecurity ant matchers.

Comment: I am not sure what is your `templateEngine` does, but at the end, your HTML should have `src="cid:logo"` inside image tag. Basically must match to the name of the inline image. When you composing the message with JavaMail, you have to set "HTML" part, not the plain text. Usially when adding the `messageBodyPart.setContent`, you need to specify content type of `"text/html"`.

Comment: Disregard the last sentence as `setText` with `true` parameter will be aware of HTML. You need to have a look on `${logo}` variable resolution. It must be resolved to `logo`.

Comment: I already tried src="cid:logo" instead of var but it didn't work.  Gmail doesn't show that image. I used width/height, display:block attr but didn't work. Seems gmail has issues processing cid resource. Base64 is already obsolete.

Comment: As advice, your question has nothing to do with Thymeleaf and spring-boot as tagged. What I would do ... I would check the inline image displayed under other clients, Thunderbird, outlook, etc. I would collect the source of the message with all the headers and post the question tagged with javamail, email, etc. Something is wrong with the email message formatting (rfc-2392), which leads to inline image is not displayed. Gmail follows specification and I doubdt they have an issue, when the message properly composed. Best regards.

Comment: Well the reason was actually different. I had figured it out.

Comment: @VivekSadh ,i am facing the same issue,how did you solve it?